# Validar en un Formrequest un valor null en campo tipo Date en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Actualmente tengo en mi FormRequest en laravel,

```
public function rules()
{
    return [ 
             'fecha2'=>'date',
```

pero al guardarla vacía me dice que es invalida y no me permite guardar, en mi DB en Mysql lo establece como tipo date, null, ¿cómo hago para que acepte valores nulos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega la regla `nullable` para que la validación pase:

```
'fecha2' => 'date|nullable',
```

Más información en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-nullable

---

Por último, asumo que el campo en la base de datos también permite null.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda